# Ubuntu Odroid XU4 - cpufrequtils - max min speed

Tags: 18.04, cpufreq

I try to set the cpu speed and governor for my ODROID XU4. If you may know, the litte board has 8 cores, running 4 @ 2GHz and the other 4 @1.5GHz.

That's also my question:
How should I set the min and max cpu speed?

I know the way of editing `/etc/default/cpufrequtils`
but this allows me only to set one `MAX_SPEED` and not different speeds for the two different quads.

Could anybody give me some support?

Thanks,
Gerry